# Location authorization status is 3

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

I am using core location for cheching the location details.While checking the authorization status ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) i got the status as 3.What does this means?

code:

```
NSLog(@" [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] %d" ,[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]);
```

Output:

[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLAuthorizationStatus):

```
typedef enum {
   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined  = 0,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted ,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ,        <---- THIS ONE!
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways  = kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse 
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

> `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`
>
> This app is authorized to use location services.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> Deprecated in iOS 8.0.